# Generating list of every other pair of integers in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I need to generate an array in Julia that contains all integers up to some number N, excluding the pair which is two integers apart. I assume that N itself is a multiple of 4. For example, if N=4, the list is

```
[1 4]
```

If N=8,

```
[1 4 5 8]
```

If N=16,

```
[1 4 5 8 9 12 13 16]
```

And so on. Is there an easy, efficient way of doing this in Julia? I tried a solution with `collect`, but I wasn't sure how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
vals = Iterators.flatten( ((i-1)*4+1, i*4) for i in 1:N÷4)
```

This generates an iterator so will work with huge `N` values.

If you want the actual values use `collect`, here is for `N=16`:

```
julia> collect(vals)
8-element Vector{Int64}:
  1
  4
  5
  8
  9
 12
 13
 16
```